# sparkSQL: "No input path specified in job", But same statement is working in spark-shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-submit

While running spark code in client mode using scala,

```
sqlContext.sql(select columname from databasename.tablename).agg(max(columname))
```

giving error

> "No input path specified in Job".

But same statement is working absolutely fine in spark-shell repl.

Can any one suggest why this error is coming

Comment: Care to share the whole stack trace? What's the Spark version?

Comment: Issue is resolved by setting/removing spark configuration parameter  from spark-submit 
`spark.sql.parquet.cacheMetadata=false`  By default this parameter set to true

Comment: That's interesting. I've never seen this param before. How did you find it and figured out that that might be the root cause? If you solved the issue, please answer your own question and accept. Thanks!

Comment: I need to get the table records count before and after table run through **spark scala framework**. since tables which I created are parquet tables. when `spark.sql.parquet.cacheMetadata=false`. parquet files from table location are not being picked up. So we were facing _No Input path specified in Job_. After removing this parameter(by observing logs), I can see parquet files are being picked up to get the records count. Now I can get the records count through Parquet API instead of Table Query like `select count(1) from table`

Comment: Can you answer your own question and accept? That'd be super helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting/removing spark configuration parameter from spark-submit `spark.sql.parquet.cacheMetadata=false`.By default this parameter set to true. Issue is Resolved after this change.